# Record separate audio (wav) and video (any) files at the same time in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm trying to create a react-native CLI app that can record audio and video at the **same time**, or at the very least allow me to extract the audio channel from the video locally.

The video stays local and the audio I send to a server for processing.  Since this just needs to just be a single-channel .wav file, I would really like to do this locally and not have to send the large video file to the server.

I've tried various combinations of libraries, such as `react-native-camera, react-native-video, react-native-audio-record, expo-camera, expo-av` but have been unable to find a solution that will allow them both access to the audio channel, am I missing something?

Basically, whenever I start recording video w/ any camera library, the audio recorder stops (and/or throws)...

I'm assuming its possible since I've used `react-native-community-voice` and recorded video at the same time in a different app, I just can't seem to get an audio library that will work with a camera video record.

Any pointers?